# Graphs disappear sometimes with QT C++

Tags: c++, windows, qt, opengl

I'm trying to do the first [CS106L](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/index.html) assignment [GraphViz](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/assignments.html). In this project we use [QT UI framework](http://qt-project.org/) to show nodes and edges. Everything seems to work fine except the lines and nodes strangely disappear sometimes when I run the program(about one in four).

**Here's my environment**:

- OS: windows7 professional 64bit
- QT version: [Qt 5.3.0 for Windows 64-bit (VS 2013, OpenGL, 636 MB)](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/5.3/5.3.0/qt-opensource-windows-x86-msvc2013_64_opengl-5.3.0.exe)
- IDE version: visual studio 2013 Ultimate

**Here's my steps:**

- download the [starter code](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/assignments/GraphViz1.zip) and use `qmake -spec win32-msvc2013
  -tp vc` to generate the vs2013 project.
- Add the following code to main function in main.cpp

  ```
  int nodes[5][2] = { { 0, 0 }, { 10, 10 }, { 10, 20 }, { 20, 20 }, { 20, 10 } };
  int edges[4][2] = { { 1, 2 }, { 2, 3 }, { 3, 4 }, { 4, 1 } };
  SimpleGraph* myGraph = new SimpleGraph();
  vector<Node> nodeList;
  vector<Edge> edgeList;
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(nodes) / sizeof(nodes[0]); i++) {
      Node node;
      node.x = nodes[i][0];
      node.y = nodes[i][1];
      nodeList.push_back(node);
  }
  for (unsigned int i = 0; i < sizeof(edges) / sizeof(edges[0]); i++) {
      Edge edge;
      edge.start = edges[i][0];
      edge.end = edges[i][1];
      edgeList.push_back(edge);
  }
  InitGraphVisualizer(*myGraph);
  myGraph->nodes = nodeList;
  myGraph->edges = edgeList;
  DrawGraph(*myGraph);
  return 0;
  ```
- I get a square with these code, but the images I draw will not always appear when I run the exe file(appear about 3 in 4)

Besides, I want to ask how can I change the edges/nodes configuration and refresh the graph. I have tried:

```
InitGraphVisualizer(*myGraph);
myGraph->nodes = nodeList;
myGraph->edges = edgeList;
DrawGraph(*myGraph);
myGraph->edges.push_back({ 1, 3 });
DrawGraph(*myGraph);
```

but failed.

Comment: Why does the code in the link you provided use a semaphore? That doesn't seem right to me.

Comment: I get code from http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106l/assignments.html.  @D Drmmr

Comment: That "starter" code from Stanford just makes me cry. Whoever wrote it should be publicly shamed, they had zero understanding of Qt and just convoluted everything oh so hopelessly. The best advice I can give you is: do *not* use that code, except for the `paintEvent`. I also find that calling this example "graphviz" is **very misleading**, as you're most definitely *not* using the [graphviz](http://www.graphviz.org) project.

Comment: Your problem is, most likely, that there are two threads of execution, and your code executes in a non-gui thread, and objects get created in wrong threads, and there's no proper interthread communication, and stuff like that. It just makes me mad that someone would shove this abomination onto unsuspecting students. It's not your fault. You tried to rely on a "starter" that is hopelessly broken. Yes, I wrote similarly arcane and buggy multithreaded code, but that was back when I had relatively little clue as to what I'm doing. TAs and profs should know better.

Comment: Your advice is really helpful. But I'm not a stanford student. I don't know whether profs and TAs would like to waste their time on responding my email. But I will give it a try